# Linux serial port programming c_cc character configurations

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

By referencing the source in the following link :
[Serial_Port_Programming_How_To](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html#AEN125)

I found out that there are c_cc character configurations there.
After searching around the affections, I did not find the exact answer to this.
I try to comment out each line of these c_cc configurations and found out the following line does affect the output.

```
newtio.c_cc[VEOF]     = 4;
```

Can anyone explain the meaning of this and possibly for the rest of these?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked e.g. [the termios manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)?

Comment: thanks, would you please post your answer to the "answer reply" so that I can check it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, the manual page for [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) is a starting point:

> **VEOF**
>
> (004, EOT, Ctrl-D) End-of-file character (EOF).  More
> precisely: this character causes the pending tty buffer to be
> sent to the waiting user program without waiting for end-of-line.  If it is the first character of the line, the read(2)
> in the user program returns 0, which signifies end-of-file.
> Recognized when ICANON is set, and then not passed as input.

In the context of the given link, [3.1. Canonical Input Processing](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html#AEN125), the OP has observed that commenting out an assignment

```
newtio.c_cc[VEOF]     = 4;
```

prevents `^D` from working as expected.  That, and similar assignments correspond to the settings one might use for a shell script with [`stty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html).  Internally (using *termios*) those are set to an *undefined* value when assigned `0xff`, but a default `0x00` is almost as good.